# Finding the number of concurrent days two events happen over the course of time using a calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a structure

(rx)

```
clmID         int
patid         int
drugclass     char(3)
drugName      char(25)
fillDate      date
scriptEndDate date
strength      int
```

And a query

```
;with PatientDrugList(patid, filldate,scriptEndDate,drugClass,strength)      
as      
(      
select rx.patid,rx.fillDate,rx.scriptEndDate,rx.drugClass,rx.strength      
 from rx      
)      
,      
DrugList(drugName)      
as      
(      
select x.drugClass      
from (values('h3a'),('h6h'))      
as x(drugClass)      
where x.drugClass is not null      
)      
SELECT PD.patid, C.calendarDate AS overlap_date      
 FROM PatientDrugList AS PD, Calendar AS C      
 WHERE drugClass IN ('h3a','h6h')      
  AND calendardate BETWEEN filldate AND scriptenddate      
 GROUP BY PD.patid, C.CalendarDate      
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT drugClass) = 2     
order by pd.patid,c.calendarDate
```

The `Calendar` is simple a calendar table with all possible dates throughout the length of the study with no other columns.

My query returns data that looks like

[image]

The overlap_date represents every day that a person was prescribed a drug in the two classes listed after the PatientDrugList CTE.

I would like to find the number of consecutive days that each person was prescribed both families of drugs.  I can't use a simple `max` and `min` aggregate because that wouldn't tell me if someone stopped this regimen and then started again.  What is an efficient way to find this out?

EDIT: The row constructor in the DrugList CTE should be a parameter for a stored procedure and was amended for the purposes of this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for consecutive sequences of dates.  The key observation is that if you subtract a sequence from the dates, you'll get a constant date.  This defines a group of dates all in sequence, which can then be grouped.

```
select patid
  ,MIN(overlap_date) as start_overlap
  ,MAX(overlap_date) as end_overlap
  from(select cte.*,(dateadd(day,row_number() over(partition by patid order by overlap_Date),overlap_date)) as groupDate
        from cte
      )t
  group by patid, groupDate
```

This code is untested, so it might have some typos.

Comment: well, at least i know i'm thinking right, my initial inclination was to do almost the same thing: add a row number and see if the max-min overlap_date equaled the row number.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie . . . Good thinking.  It turns out that you do not need the calendar table.  Rather ironic.  For many problems involving dates, the calendar table is the solution.

Comment: I was a little busy with other things and hesitated to try the window function method as my solution, it's good to know that my time here on SO is finally starting to pay off.  I couldn't figure out in my head if it would help with non-consecutive dates.  I hadn't ever done anything with a calendar table (although I've been told how invaluable they are) and wanted to start testing out how to work with them.

Answer (score -2):

You need to pivot on something and a max and min work that out.  Can you state if someone had both drugs on a date pivot?  Then you would be limiting by date if I understand your question correctly.

EG Example SQL:

```
  declare @Temp table ( person varchar(8), dt date, drug varchar(8));

insert into @Temp values ('Brett','1-1-2013', 'h3a'),('Brett', '1-1-2013', 'h6h'),('Brett','1-2-2013', 'h3a'),('Brett', '1-2-2013', 'h6h'),('Joe', '1-1-2013', 'H3a'),('Joe', '1-2-2013', 'h6h');

with a as 
    (
    select
        person
    ,   dt
    ,   max(case when drug = 'h3a' then 1 else 0 end) as h3a
    ,   max(case when drug = 'h6h' then 1 else 0 end) as h6h
    from @Temp
    group by person, dt
    )
, b as 
    (
    select *, case when h3a = 1 and h6h = 1 then 1 end as Logic
    from a
    )
select person, count(Logic) as DaysOnBothPresriptions
from b
group by person
```